# Global vars in python

Tags: python, global

I currently have some class foo() with some variables that are not only shared among all instances of the foo class, but also by other classes bar.

i.e.

```
class foo():
    __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class bar():
    __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

One solution would be to make a and b class variables, but how do I do that cleanly during construction? Could I just put both classes in the same file and have them reference some global variables a and b? Is that bad practice?

Comment: Your question is not clear. what are these variables? how are they shared? it doesn't make sense for `bar.__init__` to initialize variables for `foo`.

Comment: `foo`'s instance variables are not shared at all. There are no class variables in the code you have shown. Or maybe you want to share the *objects* these variables are holding.

Comment: If you're just asking "Could I… have them reference some global variables?", the answer is obviously yes. But presumably you're asking "Would this accomplish what I want?" or "Is this the best way to accomplish what I want?", and we have no idea what you want, so there is no way to answer that. This is either an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), or not a question at all.

Answer (score 6):

Since you did not provide your intention or real-world situation, I'll just provide some ways of sharing variable access.

1st option: global.

```
a=b=None

class foo():
    def __init__(self, _a, _b):
        global a, b
        a, b = _a, _b

class bar():
    def __init__(self, _a, _b):
        global a, b
        a, b = _a, _b
```

2nd option: foo's class vars

```
class foo():
    a = b = None
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        foo.a, foo.b = a, b

class bar():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        foo.a, foo.b = a, b
```

3rd option: inheritance

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

class bar(foo):
    pass
```

4th option: outer class

```
class outer():
    a = b = None
    class foo():
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            outer.a, outer.b = a, b

    class bar():
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            outer.a, outer.b = a, b
```

5th option: compsition

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

class bar():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.foo = foo(a,b)
```

6th option: closure over outer-function local variables

```
def outer():
    a = b = None
    class foo():
        def __init__(self, _a, _b):
            nonlocal a, b
            a, b = _a, _b

    class bar():
        def __init__(self, _a, _b):
            nonlocal a, b
            a, b = _a, _b

    ... #things with foo and bar
```

7th option: closure over foo's `__init__` local variables.

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b
        class bar():
            nonlocal a, b
            #do things with a and b directly

        self.bar = bar()
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of `def`s. Also, your 5th option is wrong; you want something like `self.foo = foo(a, b)`. And your 6th too. I'm not sure what you were trying there, but that code just rebinds `a` and `b` to the actual parameters passed to each initialization of either class. Also, 7th is just as function-local as 6th; it's just that you're using implicit `nonlocal` (or, if you assign to `a` or `b`, not…), and capturing the closure to presumably use later.

Comment: @abarnert yeah, I will blame the late hour for the `defs` and 5 :)

Comment: and I don't understand your comment about 7. It's not an implicit non-local - there should be only reading there, no assignments.

Comment: If you assign, it's implicitly local; if you don't assign, it's implicitly non-local (it becomes a closure load if there's a local name at the time of definition, a global load if not—exactly as if you'd added a `nonlocal` statement). The difference between 6 and 7 is that 6 allows assigning, 7 doesn't, but calling them "function-local" and "closure" is misleading—they're both closures over function-local variables if you don't assign, and 7 isn't using a closure at all if you do assign.

Comment: @abarnert I think I understood your point. I changed the description to be less misleading (I believe). My point in putting both these examples is that in 6 you treat `a` and `b` in a (symmetric) way that resembels global variables, and 7 suits only very specific kind of situations.

Comment: If you still think the description or the examples are misleading, you can fix them.

Comment: Looks good now. Sorry for harping on you; it's just that it was such a great answer other than a couple of confusing words (and the initial silly mistakes) that it deserved to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

By inheriting from Foo, you'll be adopting Foo's construction method as well so it will act the same way. If you need to override it, you can set it up this way in Bar:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c):
    super(Bar, self).__init__(a, b)
    self.c = c
```

`super` will call your base class' method first (in this case, Foo) and then allow you to add on if you'd like. [Here's the documentation on super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), if you're interested.

Comment: Inheritance is a good solution here only if it fits the situation. Inheritance is not for reuse, but for subtyping.

Comment: @Elazar: Sorry, I have to disagree because [subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) itself is just a kind of reuse.

Comment: @martineau: Sure, subtyping is reuse of types (which typically also means interfaces, etc.), but I think Elazar was trying to say that inheritance is for reuse of types, interfaces, etc., not for reuse of implementation, storage, etc., and that's a valid point. (There are things that fall in the middle and are up for debate, like layout—but those things rarely matter in Python.)

Comment: @abarnert: Still I don't agree. Inheritance is for the reuse of properties or aspects of the superclass, _whatever_ that may be -- none are illegal or off-limits. Of course that doesn't mean they're equal in all aspects, as some may be more fragile than others and result in there being more coupling between the two classes than would be wise.

Comment: @martineau: Let's try it this way: As a rule of thumb, inheritance for code reuse is bad, except in certain special situations (e.g., ABC mixins). However, like any rule of thumb, it's not rigid and invariable—and, like most rules of thumb, Python's dynamic and flexible nature means that exceptions are well-motivated more often than in, say, Java.

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to make an object that stores the shared information, then pass that when instantiating the classes that need it. Often this is some kind of configuration information, so we'll call the class `Config`:

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    # default values
    number = 0
    text   = "Nothing"
```

Since Python is duck-typed, any object can be used to hold this configuration; it can be an instance of a class or the class itself. The former is handy when the data is specified at runtime. The latter can be convenient since it allows the programmer to define the various bundles of attributes using inheritance at coding time.  The `Config` class here lets you have it either way: you can instantiate it, passing keyword arguments with the shared values, or you can subclass it, providing the shared values as class attributes.

In your `Foo` and `Bar` classes you then just accept the shared data in the constructor:

```
# these classes both need certain pieces of data
# but are not related by inheritance

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, shared):
        self.shared = shared

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
```

And then you can either instantiate the `Config` class, or define a subclass, and pass the resulting object to the new objects:

```
# use an instance
adams_config = Config(text="Don't Panic", number=42)
foo1, bar1 = Foo(adams_config), Bar(adams_config)

# use a subclass
class LincolnConfig(Config):
    number = 87 
    text   = "Four score and seven years ago"
foo2, bar2 = Foo(LincolnConfig), Bar(LincolnConfig)
```

Now methods of your `Foo` and `Bar` class can get `self.shared.number` or `self.config.text` (and so on) to access the data.

Since the instances of your various classes are all holding references to the same object, a change to e.g. `adams_config` or `LincolnConfig` would be seen by any instance of any class that holds a reference to one of these objects. If this isn't the behavior you want, you could fish the data you want to "freeze" out of the config object at instantiation and set it as attributes of your instance.

You could also just use a dictionary for data you want to access in various places, but I think the benefits of inheritance and attribute-access syntax are a good argument for doing it with classes.

You could even have a global configuration object that is used as a default value so you don't need to explicitly specify it if you want things to "just work." Here we'll just use the `Config` class itself for that, since it already has default values for the attributes we're interested in:

```
class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self, config=Config):
        self.config = config
```

By using this approach instead of global variables, you make it easier for clients using your objects to have numerous instances with *different* settings, rather than being limited to one "bundle" of settings for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "cleanly during construction"

You can use class variables by defining them outside the function like:

```
class A:
  x = 1
  def __init__(self):
     pass
```

And just call A.x whenever you need the variable, within other classes or wherever